# new Date() vs Date() and why does it return a different time (-2 hours)?

Tags: javascript, date, time

I have these 2 console logs, but they return different times (-2 hours off).

```
console.log(new Date()) // Date 2015-04-20T15:37:23.000Z
console.log(Date()) // "Mon Apr 20 2015 17:37:23 GMT+0200 (CEST)"
```

I know using Data() is the same as using the constructor and calling  .toString().

However, i do need the Date() time and not the new Date() time. So why is it returning the wrong time and how can i reset it to output the correct one?

thx,

Comment: These aren't different times. `15:37` in GMT-0 and `17:37` in GMT+2 are exactly the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So why is it returning the wrong time and how can i reset it to output the correct one?

Your first statement is calling `console.log` with a `Date` object. It appears that whatever browser/console plugin you're using chooses to display that `Date` object by using an ISO-8601 string in UTC. E.g., the format is chosen by the `console` implementation.

Your second statement is calling `console.log` with a **string**, so the format is chosen by the `Date` implementation. The [specification makes **no requirement** on what that string format must be](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.2) from JavaScript engine to JavaScript engine (yes, really*) other than that it must be in the local timezone.

Apparently, on your browser, the `console` implementation and the `Date#toString` implementation don't match up.

> However, i do need the Date() time and not the new Date() time.

Those strings define the same moment in time (plus or minus a couple of microseconds); it's just that the strings have been prepared with different timezone settings.

If you need to log a **string** to the console in local time, use

```
console.log(String(new Date()));
```

...to reliably get the string from the `Date` object, not something generated by the `console`.

---

* Yup, the format you get from `Date#toString` is undefined and entirely up to the JavaScript implementation; the only requirement is that `Date()` and `Date.parse()` can both parse the string `toString` outputs and get back to the original date. (JavaScript didn't even have a standard date/time format [until ES5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15), and it only applies to the `toISOString` method, not `toString`. And ES5 got it slightly wrong and it had to be [amended in ES6](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-date-time-string-format), leading to the unfortunate situation at the moment where Chrome does one thing and Firefox does another when parsing strings in the new date/time format with no timezone on them.)

Comment: Indeed, when using the actual object (for instance: var x = new Date().getTime()) i do get the right date and time. Thx, for explaining.

Answer (score 2):

Those are the same time. The string generated by `Date()` just uses a different timezone, as can be seen from the `GMT+0200 (CEST)` suffix.

So if you need your time string in your local timezone, just use `.toString()` instead of `.toUTCString()`.

Comment: Seems as though (maybe) OP is asking how to change the time zone when using Date()

Comment: @TimMcClure: I wasn't sure, but he states that "*i do need the Date() time*" so it seems to be working already.