# Javascript getFullYear, getMonth, getDate not working

Tags: javascript

I'm sorry I might be flamed for this but as a newbie I would like to make this work it is on Dates. I have this code:

```
var date = new Date('Apr 21, 2015');
```

and when I alert using this code:

```js
     
    var date = new Date('Apr 21, 2015');
    alert(date.getFullYear());
    alert(date.getMonth());
    alert(date.getDate ());
```

it displays NaN. Can someone suggest me how to do this?

Comment: It works. Make example with jsfiddle.

Comment: Use firebug.. probably you have another error in your js code

Comment: what browser are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
var date = new Date('Apr 21, 2015');
```

There's [no support for that date/time format in the specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2). **If** a particular JavaScript engine supports it, it's because it's going above and beyond, and you **cannot count on it**. So you end up with a `Date` instance with the "[time value](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1)" `NaN` (the "time value" is the number of milliseconds since The Epoch — Jan 1 1970), and all of the various methods like `getFullYear` and such return `NaN`.

So:

1. If you need to parse that format, you'll have to write code to do it, or use a library like MomentJS or several others that have already been written.
2. If you just need to get that date as a `Date` instance, rather than using the string, you can build it from the multi-argument constructor:

   ```
   var date = new Date(2015, 3, 21); // Months start at 0, so 3 = April
   ```

Answer (score 2):

If you plug the following into [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), it works fine, fiving `2015`, `3` and `21` (at least under FF and IE):

```
var date = new Date('Apr 21, 2015');
alert(date.getFullYear());
alert(date.getMonth());
alert(date.getDate ());
```

So your problem may well lie elsewhere. Your best bet would be to construct a complete (but as short as possible) sample that exhibits the problem, then show us that.

If that simple code *does* cause the problem in your environment (with minimal other code), it may be that it doesn't support that format of constructor. ECMAScript specifies that, for a one-argument constructor where the argument is a string, it's like calling `Date.parse()` on that string and setting the object's value to the equivalent time value.

However, it's only *required* to handle a simplified ISO8601 format along the lines of:

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ
```

not something more free format such as `April 21, 2015`.

If the constructor has two to seven arguments, it's of the form:

```
new Date (year,month[,date[,hours[,minutes[,seconds[,ms]]]]])
```

with the individual fields given separately.

Hence there is no requirement under the standard for a given implementation to accept what you've given. A good test would be to use:

```
var date = new Date(2015,3,21);
```

and see if that fixes it.

That also gives you the same results in jsfiddle as previously and it may also fix the problem in your specific environment as well.

If you *need* to be able to parse those date formats and you don't want to restrict yourself to environments that allow them, you may need to resort to a third-party library.

Answer (score 2):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). The constructor that accepts a string value only accepts [IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14)  and  [a version of ISO8601](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)

This is the IETF RFC 2822

```
date-time       =       [ day-of-week "," ] date FWS time [CFWS]

day-of-week     =       ([FWS] day-name) / obs-day-of-week

day-name        =       "Mon" / "Tue" / "Wed" / "Thu" /
                        "Fri" / "Sat" / "Sun"

date            =       day month year

year            =       4*DIGIT / obs-year

month           =       (FWS month-name FWS) / obs-month

month-name      =       "Jan" / "Feb" / "Mar" / "Apr" /
                        "May" / "Jun" / "Jul" / "Aug" /
                        "Sep" / "Oct" / "Nov" / "Dec"

day             =       ([FWS] 1*2DIGIT) / obs-day

time            =       time-of-day FWS zone

time-of-day     =       hour ":" minute [ ":" second ]

hour            =       2DIGIT / obs-hour

minute          =       2DIGIT / obs-minute

second          =       2DIGIT / obs-second

zone            =       (( "+" / "-" ) 4DIGIT) / obs-zone
```

and the ECMA5.1 is

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ
YYYY
YYYY-MM
YYYY-MM-DD
```

Clearly your string 'Apr 21, 2015' does not fit any of the above formats so it does not work. As T.J. Crowder pointed out, if you are not using standard formats, it's very up to the engine whether or not your code works.

Comment: *"The constructor that accepts a string value only accepts IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps and..."* If MDN says that, it's wrong for the *standard* (it may well be correct for Mozilla's implementation). The specification doesn't dictate what it will parse other than the pseudo-ISO-8601 form (which they got slightly wrong in ES5 and had to fix in ES6, causing us to have different behavior in different engines at present), details in [this answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29752684/157247).

Answer (score 0):

The Date-Function works as the fallowing:

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

So this should works for you:

```
var date = new Date(2015, 3, 21);
alert(date.getFullYear());
alert(date.getMonth());
alert(date.getDate ());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to this.

```
var today = new Date("Apr 21, 2015");
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
} 

today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
alert(today);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code works in [jshint](http://jshint.com/) and [js.do](http://js.do/)

Answer (score -1):

The date string you use is not in proper ISO format, therefore the question if it works mainly depends on OS and browser locale environment settings.
Try to parse the string first and handover the result to the Date constructor like this:

```
var date = new Date(Date.parse('Apr 21, 2015'));
```

Comment: If `new Date('Apr 21, 2015')` fails, then `new Date(Date.parse('Apr 21, 2015'))` will fail, as `new Date()` just uses the same parsing algorithm.