# How to strip time element for json submission?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a form submit json data to a server which contains a date field.

If I do this:

```
var origDate = new Date();
var date = new Date(origDate.getFullYear(), origDate.getMonth(), origDate.getDate());
```

The date ends up with a time of 04:00:00 - I want the time to be just 00:00:00

I also tried date.setHours(0) but the time ended up 12:00:00

How do I make the time 00:00:00 ?

Comment: This sounds like a time zone issue.

Comment: I agree with Barmar. You should use UNIX timestamp if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
var origDate = new Date();
var date = new Date(origDate.getFullYear(), origDate.getMonth(), origDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact the time is correct but the formatting is giving wrong time values, you have to print it as a `string` and not a `Date`.

You can see the formatting difference between printing a `Date` and printing a `String` in the following Demo:

```js
var origDate = new Date();
var date = new Date(origDate.getFullYear(), origDate.getMonth(), origDate.getDate());

console.log(date);
console.log(String(date));
```

**Explanation:**

You have to print the date as String so it won't be formatted by the browser.

You can learn more about this behaviour at [new Date() vs Date() and why does it return a different time (-2 hours)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29752484/new-date-vs-date-and-why-does-it-return-a-different-time-2-hours).